# How to load Fact table in SSIS with multiple date fields

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse

I have the design shown below:

[image]

I loaded the DIM_PROJECT in the Datawarehouse and the DIM_DATE "USING LOOKUP", but when I tried to load the FACT_PROJECT_SNAPSHOT I couldn't link it to the DIM_DATE, because it has no date field, whereas the DIM_PROJECT has 4 date fields. "(date_from) and (date_to) are used in the SCD"

Question : how I can link FACT_PROJECT_SNAPSHOT to the DIM_DATE and DIM_PROJECT, while maintaining  the DIM_PROJECT date fields utilization in future "dashboards".

Comment: This is more of a datawarehousing/data modeling question rather than SSIS.

Comment: yes, I have tagged data warehouse